# How do I get date time into this format in R: 1563921031?

Tags: r, date, time, formatting

I have to query an API with a date time stamp in R, but I can't figure out how to get my date time entered in and changed into the correct format. An example of a date time stamp that works is 1563921031 and I think it's seconds since an origin time.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to numeric with `as.numeric`

```
as.numeric(datetime)
```